# bind9 can't resolve domain without prefix (prefix.domain.com)

Tags: bind

i've set up a bind dns server on my linux server.
But for some reason it can't resolve the IP for my domain when theres no prefix, like www

I tried to use nslookup and set the server to my dns servers ip

For example when I do an nslookup on www.mydomain.com it shows the IP which I defined in the bind9 zone file, but when I do an nslookup on mydomain.com there's no IP coming back :(

my zonefile:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
mydomain.com        IN SOA  ns1.mydomain.com. mail.mydomain.com. (
                2017020711 ; serial
                28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                864000     ; expire (1 week 3 days)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  ns1.mydomain.com.
            MX  10 mx01.kundenserver.de.
            MX  20 mx02.kundenserver.de.
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.


*           A   188.***.***.***
www         A   188.***.***.***
ability     A   5.***.***.***
dyn         A   91.44.***.***
nl          A   95.46.***.***
ns1         A   188.***.***.***
```

i hope you find my mistake :(

Comment: What happens when you add a `                    A 188.***.***.***` record right after the `$ORIGIN` line?

Comment: nothing, I added the A record where the mx records are and now it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a record for `@`, which represents the current origin.

It should look like:

`@       A   188.***.***.***`

This is because the wildcard (*) record only represents subdomains, not the main domain.

Answer (score -1):

As ConnorJC said, you need an @ record.  Here's a working zone file for my fake domain I use at home...  Note specifically the line

```
@       IN  A   192.168.1.2
```

Once you add that (and bump your serial) and restart the service, you should be good to go.

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.myhouse.home. root.myhouse.home. (
                 2016110202         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@           IN      NS      ns.myhouse.home.
@       IN  A   192.168.1.2
ns          IN      A       192.168.1.2
router      IN  A   192.168.1.1
ap      IN  A   192.168.1.3
server      IN      A       192.168.1.2
www         IN      A       192.168.1.2
pi      IN  A   192.168.1.2
```